# How to deal with a bean containing @Id @GeneratedVaule in Vaadin?

Tags: java, database, jpa, vaadin, vaadin7

I'm trying to make a form that will send data to the database in Vaadin.

Bean Person.java is a typical JavaBean:

```
import java.io.Serializable;
import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
import javax.persistence.Id;

@Entity
public class Person implements Serializable {

@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;
private String firstName;
private String lastName;

public Person(Long id, String firstName, String lastName) {
    this.id = id;
    this.firstName = firstName;
    this.lastName = lastName;
}

public Person() {
}

-- getters and setters --
```

The Vaadin FieldGroup looks like this:

```
FieldGroup fieldGroup = new BeanFieldGroup<Person>(Person.class);

// from the tutorial: "We need an item data source before we create the fields to be able to
// find the properties, otherwise we have to specify them by hand"
fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(new BeanItem<Person>(new Person(1L,
     "John", "Doe")));

for (Object propertyId : fieldGroup.getBoundPropertyIds()) {
    layout.addComponent(fieldGroup.buildAndBind(propertyId));
}
```

There is nothing on the page. Nothing is generated, no form fields. Am I missing something? I'm completely new to Vaadin to be honest. On the second hand, I'm wondering how to deal with the ID field. It is generated automatically, so the user shall have NO impact on this vaule... I'm lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My advice is this:

```
public class MyUI extends UI {

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {
        VerticalLayout layout = new VerticalLayout();
        FieldGroup fieldGroup = new BeanFieldGroup<Person>(Person.class);
        fieldGroup.setItemDataSource(new BeanItem<Person>(new Person(1L, "John", "Doe")));
        for (Object propertyId : fieldGroup.getUnboundPropertyIds()) {
            Field<?> field = fieldGroup.buildAndBind(propertyId);
            if ("id".equals(propertyId)) {
                field.setReadOnly(true);
            }
            layout.addComponent(field);
        }
        setContent(layout);
    }

}
```

You should use `getUnboundPropertyIds()`, because you haven't bound any propertyId to field before the iteration.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but still, the form isnt showing up... and Netbeans is saying that `addComponent` method does not exist. using `layout.addComponent(field)` aint helping either.

Comment: @dziki What type the parent class is?

Comment: sorry, tbh, I'm learning Java for less than 3 months now, so I'm not completely sure how to answer Your question... so i'll attach the first few lines of the class I'm trying to put the form into:
`public class MyVaadinUI extends UI {
    @WebServlet(value = "/*", asyncSupported = true)
    @VaadinServletConfiguration(productionMode = false, ui = MyVaadinUI.class, widgetset = "com.smtsoftware.nitecki.vaadin2test.AppWidgetSet")
    public static class Servlet extends VaadinServlet {
    }

    @Override
    protected void init(VaadinRequest request) {`

Comment: @dziki I expanded my answer.

Comment: thanks for the answer, the form is finally up. I don't want to ask about everything I need, but now I have to get this working with Spring + Hibernate, add a "Submit" button that saves the data in the database. I'm pretty sure I know how to write classes and methods using JPA to persist the data (ive done it in JSF a few times - but without any traces of spring and hibernate). Just give me one advice - where should I start looking? And how the hell add this SUBMIT button using a method from a java class responsible for persisting? :D

Comment: @dziki Some example: [spring-hibernate](http://www.studytrails.com/frameworks/spring/spring-hibernate-jpa.jsp), [spring-vaadin](https://vaadin.com/wiki/-/wiki/Main/Spring+Integration), [vaadin-form-submit](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/datamodel.itembinding.html)